# Using curl as a test

Tags: curl

I'm writing Puppet configuration to automate the creation of an Elastic Search repository resource. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's no way to specify this configuration in the Elastic Search YAML configuration file, so I'm stuck with HTTP and curl. I've declared the following as resources:

```
file { 'curator_repository_config':
    path    => "${elasticsearch::install_dir}/config/s3-repository.json",
    owner   => $elasticsearch::user,
    group   => $elasticsearch::user,
    mode    => '0400',
    content => template('chromeriver/curator/s3-repository.json.erb'),
}

exec { 'create_es_repository':
    command => "curl -is -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3' -d @${elasticsearch::install_dir}/config/s3-repository.json",
    unless  => "curl -is -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3'",
    path    => '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin',
    user    => $elasticsearch::user,
    require => [
        Service['elasticsearch'],
        File['curator_repository_config']
    ]
}
```

Understanding Puppet configuration isn't necessary to answer this question, but the above essentially creates a file called `s3-repository.json` which contains configuration details with are ultimately used in the POST to Elastic Search.

The second resource conditionally executes, only running if the return code from the following command is non-zero. It essentially does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! curl -is -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3' &>/dev/null; then
    curl -is -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3' @/path/to/s3-repository.json
fi
```

The problem I'm having is that `curl` returns `0` for a `404` on the `GET` request. I'd like to have `curl` return `1` if the response is a non-200 response.

Is there an easy way to do this with `curl`?

Comment: Use the `-f` option

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer in the `--fail` option to `curl`. By passing this option, `curl` returns a non-zero exit code for non-200 responses:

```
curl -i -X GET --fail 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3'
```